# Comparing Class Properties of type Object

Tags: c#

I'm trying to log history of each property of an object after it's been updated only if it has changed. Instead of doing an if statement for each property i've decided to loop through each property where i've defined a custom attribute to filter out the ones i don't want to log, and then compare the old and new values to see if they have changed.

However checking for each obj case for equality seems large and very case specific since i also have enum types to compare. Is there a better way to accomplish this or refactor my code?

Code Example

**MyClass**

```
public class MyClassDto
{
        [Comparible]
        public MyCustomType CustomType{ get; set; }

        [Comparible]
        public DateTime? SomeDate { get; set; }

        [Comparible]
        public decimal? SomeDecimalValue { get; set; }

        [Comparible]
        public int? SomeIntValue { get; set; }

       // Other Non Custom Attribute Type Properties
}
```

**Add History Helper Function**

```
public void AddHistory(MyClassDto prevMyObject, MyClassDto newMyObject)
{
      if (prevMyObject== null || newMyObject == null) return;

      foreach (var property in prevMyObject.GetType().GetProperties().Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof (ComparibleAttribute))))
      {
          var fieldName = property.Name;
          object prevValue = property.GetValue(prevMyObject, null);
          object newValue = newMyObject.GetType().GetProperty(property.Name).GetValue(newMyObject, null);

           if (!IsEqual(prevValue, newValue))
           {
               //Log the field, prevValue, newValue
           }
       }
  }
```

**Object Compare Function**

```
   private static bool IsEqual(object obj1, object obj2)
    {
        if (obj1 == null && obj2 == null || obj1 == obj2) return true;
        if (obj1 == null || obj2 == null) return false;

        var objType = obj1.GetType();
        if (objType == typeof (string))
        {
            return string.Equals(obj1.ToString(), obj2.ToString());
        }
        if (objType == typeof (int?))
        {
            return (Convert.ToInt32(obj1) == Convert.ToInt32(obj2));
        }
        if (objType == typeof (decimal?) || objType == typeof (decimal))
        {
            return (decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(obj1), 2) == decimal.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(obj2), 2));
        }
        if (objType == typeof (DateTime?) || objType == typeof (DateTime))
        {
            return (Convert.ToDateTime(obj1) == Convert.ToDateTime(obj2));
        }
        if (objType == typeof (ContractTrackerType))
        {
            return (((MyCustomType) obj1).Name() == ((MyCustomType ) obj2).Name());
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't actually need the separate cases for primitive types.  And for your custom types, you should have them override [`object.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47(v=vs.110).aspx), so that the equality-testing logic is encapsulated within the class.

With this, your `IsEqual` function should simply be a call to [`object.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
 private static bool IsEqual(object obj1, object obj2)
 {
     return object.Equals(obj1, obj2);
 }
```

From the notes on `object.Equals`:

> The static Equals(Object, Object) method indicates whether two objects, objA and objB, are equal. It also enables you to test objects whose value is null for equality. It compares objA and objB for equality as follows:
>
> It determines whether the two objects represent the same object reference. If they do, the method returns true. This test is equivalent to calling the ReferenceEquals method. In addition, if both objA and objB are null, the method returns true.
>
> It determines whether either objA or objB is null. If so, it returns false.
>
> If the two objects do not represent the same object reference and neither is null, it calls objA.Equals(objB) and returns the result. This means that if objA overrides the Object.Equals(Object) method, this override is called.

Comment: Thank you! Totally overlooked the object.equals method. I'm assuming when it comes to enums it will still correctly call objA.Equals(objB) which evaluates it's actual values or do enum's need to overide object.Equals?

Comment: @Kaustix yes, enum types have their own override of Equals: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bafh2by(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks! Please have a cookie!